# Regex for deleting everything (including multiple lines) after a string "foo bar"

Tags: java, regex

Need to delete everything after two words that are found together. Tried looking around for similar questions

```
str.replaceAll("foo bar(.*)", "")
```

Only seems to delete the first line.

When i add $ to the end of the regex ( foo bar.*$
)  it doesn't seem to pick anything at all? Any ideas why?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's as simple as finding 2 words, you could use `indexOf` to find them, then use `substring` to trim the String to drop everything after the two words.

```
String keyWord = "key word";
String input = "some\ntext\nkey word is here\nand more text\nto follow";
int pos = input.indexOf(keyWord);
if (pos != -1) {
    String trimmed = input.substring(0, pos + keyWord.length());
    System.err.println("'" + trimmed + "'");
}
```

The code above assumes you want to keep the key word; if you don't want to keep it, just drop the `+ keyword.length()` in the `substring`.

If you do want to use a regular expression, pass the `Pattern.DOTALL` flag to have the dot match line endings. You also need to change the regex to capture what you want to keep, not what you want to discard (as your example has it):

```
String keyWordRegex = "key\\s+word";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(.*\\b" + keyWordRegex + "\\b).*", Pattern.DOTALL);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(input);
String replaced = matcher.replaceAll("$1");
System.err.println("'" + replaced + "'");
```

The regex works like this:

- first, opening brace to start capturing
- capture anything (dot) zero to infinite times (star)
- then a word boundary, so that it does only match "key word" but not "masterkey word"
- then your key word regex, in this example I made it to be "key", one or more (plus) spaces (\s), and "word"
- word boundary again
- close the capture group
- allow any number (star) of characters (dot)

Comment: The regex match could be used the same way as the indexed version. You can get the index of the match and its length, then do the truncation as before. That's probably better than making the regex more complex than it has to be.

Answer (score 1):

Use `Single Line Mode` matching using flag `?s`.

`str = str.replaceAll("(?s)foo bar(.*)", "");`

If using regex is not mandatory, you can simply use the following:

`str = str.indexOf("foo bar") == -1 ? str : str.substring(0, str.indexOf("foo bar"));`

Answer (score 1):

you can try below solution. 
It's delete all character after the `foo bar` is found.

```
String a = "hell fdshf fdfjk foo bar ffsd fsajkh vsfdsv" ;
String as = a.split("foo bar")[0];
System.out.println(as);
```

**Output**

`hell fdshf fdfjk`

Comment: Hello chirag, Your answer is best and very use full.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to use regex. You can use simple string manipulation concept.

```
String str = "testing test foo bar  test  foo bar test \n testing all  \n foo bar(.*) tester";

        String boundaryValueText = "foo bar";
        int boundaryValueIndex = str.indexOf(boundaryValueText);
        String parsedContent = boundaryValueIndex != -1 ? new StringBuilder(str)
                .delete(boundaryValueIndex + boundaryValueText.length(), str.length()).toString() : str;
```

Comment: Thanks ..Will add multi-line  support in example.

Comment: Can you provide the input for which it will not work.

Comment: I tried with String str="foo bar(.*)  test  foo bar(.*)  test \n testing all foo bar(.*) tester"; and its working.

Comment: I tried and its working . You can cross check.  String str="foo bar(.*) test foo bar(.*) test \n testing all foo bar(.*) tester"; str.replaceAll("foo bar\\(\\.\\*\\)", "");